# How might I be able to link jquery file upload, ajax, and jquery file download on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Thanks!

I'm a complete beginner but I'd like to know even in a generic way so that my users could upload a file to another user's directory, the file gets saved on to a server and the receiving user could download it when the upload gets finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're a complete beginner, I won't give you a lot of code; instead, I'll show you the overview of what you can do, and hopefully that will give you a much more refined approach to adopt:

---

**Rails Uploads Using [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)**

What makes Rails so powerful is the [gem ecosystem](http://rubygems.org) - these are little plugins which give you functionality outside the scope of the Rails framework. You can get Gems for everything from file uploads to CSS frameworks - all for free

One of the most important & popular gems for Rails is [Paperclip](http://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip) (and you have [Carrierwave](http://rubygems.org/gems/carrierwave) which also does the same job). These are what you use to process image uploads in Rails

Since you're a total beginner, you should really watch this Railscast about how to [upload files with Rails using Paperclip](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip):

[image: RailsCast Paperclip]

There are also a lot of other tutorials on Paperclip:

- [Heroku's Paperclip Tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3)
- [Simple Paperclip tutorial](http://patshaughnessy.net/2009/4/30/paperclip-sample-app)
- [Another Paperclup tutorial](http://blog.railsthemes.com/2013/05/14/my-favorite-gem-paperclip/)

---

I would write some more updates about Paperclip & JQuery, but I think you should get your head around the upload process first

Comment: thank you so much, a lot of stackoverflowers would have declined to answer this kind of generic question, but you were so kind to answer it so elegantly. Thanks for the info again!

Comment: No problem! If you need any more information, please just ask!